# Kafka Streams: KTable to KStream One-to-Many transformation

Tags: java, apache-kafka, one-to-many, apache-kafka-streams

I am not sure if this is possible but here's my scenario:

- I have a KTable with Long as key and an ArrayList as value
- When value (arraylist of ids) for a particular key in the KTable changes, I want to publish a message on a topic for each individual id in the arraylist.
- Lets say I have a record `<1, [2,3]>` in KTable. If this now changes to `<1, [2,4]>`, I want to publish messages on `output_topic` - `<2, Object>, <4,Object>`. Object is derived from other attributes in the KTable value.

To this end, I was thinking along the lines of converting the KTable to a KStream by providing it a custom `KeyValueMapper` and then publishing the Stream on a topic. I have run into the issue that from what I can see online a `KeyValueMapper` can only transform one message at a time so its good for one-to-one mapping. In my scenario, I want to convert one incoming message into multiple outgoing message. Here's my code:

```
final KeyValueMapper<Long, CustomGroup, KeyValue<Long, CustomCluster>> outputMapper = new KeyValueMapper<Long, CustomGroup,KeyValue<Long, CustomCluster>>() {
            public KeyValue<Long, CustomCluster> apply(Long key, CustomGroup value) {

            ArrayList<KeyValue<Long, CustomCluster>> result = new ArrayList<>(value.compositeIds.size());
            for(Long compositeId : value.compositeIds) {
                CustomCluster c = new CustomCluster(value.appSettingID, value.appSettingName, compositeId, value.user);
                c.clusters = new HashSet<Cluster>();
                c.clusters.add(new Cluster(c.clusterId, c.clusterName));
                result.add(new KeyValue<>(compositeId, c));
            }

            return result;

        }
    };

KStream<Long, CustomCluster> outputStream = cgTable.toStream(outputMapper);
```

result is the list that contains all my messages. This code gives me a syntax error because it expects to return a single KeyValue object and not an ArrayList of KeyValue objects.

Is there a way to get the outputMapper to work the way I am envisaging it? Is there another way to accomplish the task. Basically, I need to send multiple messages that are derived from the value of ktable record on a particular topic.

I was able to accomplish the task when the incoming change was in a KStream rather than a KTable. KSTream offered a flatMap method to do that.

```
final KeyValueMapper<Long, CustomGroup, Iterable<KeyValue<Long, CustomCluster>>> outputMapper = new KeyValueMapper<Long, CustomGroup, Iterable<KeyValue<Long, CustomCluster>>>() {
        public Iterable<KeyValue<Long, CustomCluster>> apply(Long key, CustomGroup value) {

            ArrayList<KeyValue<Long, CustomCluster>> result = new ArrayList<>(value.compositeIds.size());
            for(Long compositeId : value.compositeIds) {
                CustomCluster c = new CustomCluster(value.appSettingID, value.appSettingName, compositeId, value.user);
                c.clusters = new HashSet<Cluster>();
                c.clusters.add(new Cluster(c.clusterId, c.clusterName));
                result.add(new KeyValue<>(compositeId, c));
            }

            return result;

        }
    };

KStream<Long, CustomCluster> outputStream = cgStream.flatMap(outputMapper);
```

So the question is whether KTable provides an equivalent to KStream's flatMap method. I hope I wasn't too convoluted in my question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you not chain the two approaches?  Something like `cgTable.toStream().flatMap(outputMapper);`

Comment: Yes chaining it seems to work. Thanks. I had it first in separate lines but that was giving me syntax errors. I also wanted to know if there was a better solution